# H2 db: how to run a SQL script in the current directory

Tags: h2, run-script

I'm trying to do this in an arbitrary folder:

```
java -cp .;e:\tools\h2\bin\*  org.h2.tools.RunScript -url myDBURI  -script CreateDatabase.sql
```

CreateDatabase.sql is in the current folder.
Inside it I have:

```
runscript from 'classpath:/DropSchemas.sql';
```

I have also tried

```
runscript from 'DropSchemas.sql';
runscript from './DropSchemas.sql';
```

When I do this I get a file not found error fror DropSchemas.sql:

Exception in thread "main" org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: IO Exception: "java.io.
FileNotFoundException: resource /DropSchemas.sql"; "classpath:/DropSchemas.sql";
 SQL statement:

```
runscript from 'classpath:/DropSchemas.sql' [90031-172]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:329)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:158)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.convertIOException(DbException.java:315)
    at org.h2.command.dml.ScriptBase.openInput(ScriptBase.java:168)
    at org.h2.command.dml.RunScriptCommand.update(RunScriptCommand.java:45)
    at org.h2.command.CommandContainer.update(CommandContainer.java:79)
    at org.h2.command.Command.executeUpdate(Command.java:235)
    at org.h2.server.TcpServerThread.process(TcpServerThread.java:335)
    at org.h2.server.TcpServerThread.run(TcpServerThread.java:151)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: resource /DropSchemas.sql
    at org.h2.store.fs.FilePathDisk.newInputStream(FilePathDisk.java:298)
    at org.h2.store.fs.FileUtils.newInputStream(FileUtils.java:206)
    at org.h2.command.dml.ScriptBase.openInput(ScriptBase.java:166)
    ... 6 more

    at org.h2.engine.SessionRemote.done(SessionRemote.java:579)
    at org.h2.command.CommandRemote.executeUpdate(CommandRemote.java:186)
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcStatement.executeInternal(JdbcStatement.java:180)
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcStatement.execute(JdbcStatement.java:155)
    at org.h2.tools.RunScript.process(RunScript.java:255)
    at org.h2.tools.RunScript.process(RunScript.java:188)
    at org.h2.tools.RunScript.process(RunScript.java:319)
    at org.h2.tools.RunScript.runTool(RunScript.java:142)
    at org.h2.tools.RunScript.main(RunScript.java:69)
```

It works if I specify the absolute path to dropschemas.sql but that's not a good way to build my script.

How do I create a master script that runs other scripts in a portable manner?

Thanks
Michael

Comment: FYI I'm on Windows 8 x64, Java 7

Comment: It works for me. I run the tools like this: `java org.h2.tools.RunScript -url jdbc:h2:test -script test1.sql`. The file `test1.sql` contains `runscript from 'test2.sql';` and the file `test2.sql` contains `create table test(id int);`.